# How can I parse android activity_main.xml file and modify it?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I want to parse android activity_main.xml and add custom properties tag of my views in it pragmatically.

**For example: (original)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.test.compoundviewcreation.Slider"
        android:id="@+id/view4"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**After modification:** (custom:sliderLabel tag added)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <view
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.test.compoundviewcreation.Slider"
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        custom:sliderLabel="Custom SLider Label"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried with DOM Parser but it cant parse it and shows xml doc is null. Any idea?

Comment: Why programatically? What are the requirements? Add same attribute to every `<view>`? With the information provided I would do it by hand.

Comment: @Birei Because I don't want to modify it by hand. Android studio layout designer properties panel only shows android properties, not custom properties. I will create another properties panel through a simple java app, which will allow to enter custom properties.  So, I need to parse this XML file. Yes, I want to add same attribute to different custom view.

Comment: My supervisor doesn't want to do it manually and I want to provide him one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `joox` library, imported using [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) like:

```
compile 'org.jooq:joox:1.3.0'
```

So then you can use `find()` method to get all `<view>` elements and `attr()` method to assign your custom attribute, like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.joox.Match;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import static org.joox.JOOX.$;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {
        final Match $m = $(new File(args[0]));
        $m.find("view").attr("custom:sliderLabel", "Custom SLider Label");
        $m.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

I will assume your `xml` is well-formed (not like your example) and that you give the `xml` file as argument to the program. Also I added another `<view>` to show that it changes both of them.

Note that output is neither well formatted nor ordered (attributes), but that is not a `xml` problem. Result:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <view android:id="@+id/view4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" class="com.test.compoundviewcreation.Slider" custom:sliderLabel="Custom SLider Label"/>

    <view android:id="@+id/view5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" class="com.test.compoundviewcreation.Slider" custom:sliderLabel="Custom SLider Label"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**UPDATE**: Based in comments, assuming you want to only append the new attribute to the `<view>` with `id` of `view4`, you need to use namespaces. I prefer to hanlde these cases with `xpath()` method, like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {
    final Match $m = $(new File(args[0]));
    $m.namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android")
            .xpath("//view[@android:id='@+id/view4']")
            .attr("custom:sliderLabel", "Custom SLider Label");
    $m.write(System.out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working. I would be really glad, if you please help me with how can I use the filter and how to write the xml. The following 2 commands are not working:  $m.find("view").filter("custom:sliderLabel").after("<book id=\"6\"/>");  and $m.write("C:\\Users\\Cubex\\Desktop\\customer1.xml"); . I did not found any documentation of joox and not understanding where is my mistake. Thank you so much for the amazing solution.

Comment: @Newbie23: For second one you need a `File` object, so instantiate one as a parameter to `write()` method, like: `$m.write(new File("your/path/to/file"))`. For the first one, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanksss!! I want to append different new attributes for different ids. So, far I have successful to find list of ids. If the filter function works, that would also served the purpose. Right now, if I want to change the custom:sliderLabel only for view 4, not for view5 (say there are two views), how can I do it?

Comment: I mean, I wanted to do following but its not working:  $m.find("view").filter("@+id/view4").attr("custom:sliderLabel", "Custom SLider Label");

Comment: @Newbie23: I've updated the answer to include that fact.